# Using ArcObjects ITextSymbol.GetTextSize in Python to define two input variables that get populated by method

Tags: python, arcobjects, nameerror

I am using Python 2.6 and ArcObjects in ArcGIS 10.0 to build and draw, among other things, graphic text on the current display.  At one point I need to use the ITextSymbol.GetTextSize method.  In a function called BuildSignGraphic() have the following:

```
def BuildSignGraphic(pFeature, annoFC):
    .
    .
    pTextSymbol.GetTextSize(pDisplay.hDC, pDisplay.DisplayTransformation, txt, dblX, dblY)
    .
    .
```

When I run my code I get a name error:

NameError: global name 'dblX' is not defined

In VB.NET, the dblX variable would be explicitly declared, but Python doesn't do this.

Because the dblX and dblY variables are *input* and get populated by the method, how do I go about defining these two variables so that Python can recognize them?

This is an uncommon syntax for a method in ArcObjects, but I think it does occur elsewhere in ArcObjects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out params behave differently in comtypes, they come in the return value of the call:

```
dblx, dbly = pTextSymbol.GetTextSize(pDisplay.hDC, pDisplay.DisplayTransformation, txt)
```